# Passing Variables/ID on dynamic click event(context menu)

Tags: c#, contextmenu

how do i pass variables or ID to a specific click event in a dynamic loop of a context menu..my goal is to load the names of the technician in context menu dynamically and each of their click event must pass their id then call my method named assign_tech()

my code so far and what i tried are here

```
    void loadContext()
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_technician`";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = constrings.GetDBConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {


                            ToolStripMenuItem cm = startToolStripMenuItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
                            cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString()).Click += MyMethod;
                            //cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString()).Click += (sender, e) => { MyMethod(sender, e); };
                            //cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString()).Click += (_sender, _e) => 
                            //{

                                  // tech_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);

                            //    //MessageBox.Show(tech_id.ToString());

                            //};

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CMessageBox m = new CMessageBox("error\n" + ex);
                m.ShowDialog();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

My code for the click event

```
 void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("test");
        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
        DialogueBox db = new DialogueBox("Are you sure you want to assign this Record!");

        dr = db.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            assign_tech();
            loadData();
            loadTechnicianData();
        }
    }
```

My code for the assign tech

```
      void assign_tech()
    {
        if (tech_id>0)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = constrings.GetDBConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    query = "UPDATE `tbl_job_order` SET `t_id` = @tech_id, status= 'Servicing' WHERE `tbl_job_order`.`j_id` = @id;";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech_id", tech_id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", selected_id);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CMessageBox m = new CMessageBox("error \n" + ex);
                    m.ShowDialog();
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStripDropDownItem` inherits a `Tag` property from `ToolStripItem` specifically for this purpose.  `Tag` is an `object` property, so you can assign anything you like to it.  In the API documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.tag?view=netframework-4.8#examples)) they use it to hold a string, but you can put anything you like in there.

In your `loadContext` method in the inner loop set the `Tag` property of the newly-created `ToolStripDropDownItem` to the ID of your `tbl_technician` record:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ToolStripMenuItem cm = startToolStripMenuItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
    var item = cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString());
    item.Click += MyMethod;
    item.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
}
```

Now in your handler you can extract the ID value and pass it to `assign_tech` method:

```
void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get tech id from sender's Tag
    if (!(sender is TooStripDropDownItem item) || !(item.Tag is int tech_id))
        return;

    // MessageBox.Show("test");
    DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
    DialogueBox db = new DialogueBox("Are you sure you want to assign this Record!");

    dr = db.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        assign_tech(tech_id);
        loadData();
        loadTechnicianData();
    }
}
```

If you want to get a bit deeper you can load your record into an appropriate class instance and store that instance in the `Tag` property so that you have more information available to you.

Comment: how would i store records properly? i dont mind learning new things..right now im storing datas on a class called profile.cs but they are all in static strings and integer dunno if that is a right way..

Comment: Look into ORMs like Linq2DB or EntityFrameworks.  They let you work with tables as if they were just another collection of objects, and handle most of the boring bits of doing actual queries to the database server.  Linq2DB is my personal favorite.